# Python regexp stuck on some files

Tags: python, regex

I created simple scanner for text-like files (php, python, js sources) which takes list of regexps and scan all files/dirs recursively from some directory.

It is opens each file, reads content (usually it isn't quite big - max one I saw is about 10Kb) and calls for each regexp method `re.sub(my_rx_N, my_replace_callback, file_content)`.

After some testing I've found that my script is stuck on some ordinary file (i.e. there is not any specific issue/content/encoding) in these files, its looks lie any other.

I have not idea why it is appears, maybe you have?

Sample regexps:

```
((#)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\2.*)?(<\?php ?(?=(.*<\?php)))?(eval|echo)(\((base64_decode|gzinflate))+\(("|')[a-zA-Z0-9+=/]+\9\)+;( ?\?>(?=(.*<\?php)))?(.*\2/\3\2)?

<\?php(.*)\n(/\*[A-Za-z0-9 .]*\*/)\1?\nob_start\(\);(\1?\n)*\2\3\?>(\1?\n)*

preg_replace\("[]/a-zA-Z[0-9*.+]*/e[a-zA-Z0-9]*"[a-zA-Z0-9"_, (\'.)+;/=?<>]*

/\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*/.+[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9/\(\)-=;"{}\[\]\\!]+.+[ ]*/\*/\1\*/

(<\?php.?(?=(.*<\?php)))?if[ ]?\(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\()?(.?[$][A-Z_]*)(\["[0-9a-z_\\]*"\])\)[){(]*eval(\(base64_decode)?\(\4(\["[0-9a-z_\\]*"\])[{})(;A-Za-z0-9]*(.?\?>(?=(.*<\?php)))?
```

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: [Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), perhaps? Check if any of your regexes have nested quantifiers.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a failing file? In addition, the UNIX `file` utility already does a large part of what you want -- consider using that or `libmagic`, it'll save you a lot of work.

Comment: @MaxNoel it wasn't my choice, to use python.

Comment: If that's part of another program and not just a one-off script, consider using the Python bindings to `libmagic`: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: @MaxNoel I do not need to determine file type, it is defined as command line parameter like list of files extensions. I am suspecting that libmagic cannot open file, read its content and apply couple of regexps to it to check, for example, malicious entries.